# Pass parameters to PHP and build query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get PHP code like this to work:

```
<?php 
$hostname = '******';
$database = 'firstdb';
$username = '*****';
$password = '*****';
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$sortvalue = "datbase_percent";
$sortorder = "ASC";
$sql = "select * from advanced_data where category like age_group order by {$sortvalue} {$sortorder};";
$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

What I want to be able to do is define the $sortvalue and $sortorder via an AJAX call. I'm getting it now like this:

```
$.getJSON('all_get_2.php', function(data) {
```

Two questions...my PHP code doesn't work because I can't figure out the proper syntax for building the $sql variable the makes up the mySQL query. I've tried a bunch of things, but keep getting 500 errors. If I just type in the values, then the code works, so I know it's just a problem with my syntax.

Second question...what's the best way to pass a variable into $sortvalue and $sortorder from my front end? I know it's something using $.ajax, but not sure of the best way to do it. The idea is that the user would click a button, which corresponds with sorting a chart ascending or descending and reloads the chart without reloading the page. Any direction here would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried: "select * from advanced_data where category like age_group order by $sortvalue $sortorder;";

Comment: `$.getJSON` has optional data argument. See docs

Comment: use $_POST, and pass a value for it in. take a look at the jquery examples. Whatever the name is on the json object is the name you use in $_POST. $.post("yoururl.php", { abc : 123 } , success) then in PHP $_POST['abc'] == 123

Comment: `{$sortorder}` would need to have some quotes around it, like `'{$sortorder}'`. `{$sortvalue}` should be fine if it's a column name.

Comment: @LuckyBurger I could have sworn I tried that, but apparently not, because that did the trick. Now I just need to figure out how to pass those variables from jQuery. If you can add as an answer, I'll be sure to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Also fairly easy to do sorting client side since you aren't doing any filtering in query to db

Comment: `$.getJSON('foo.php?order=asc&field=whatever')`? It's just a URL, after all.

Comment: Only half related with the question, but 500 Error is a general error displayed when the errors are "hidden". I suggest displaying errors(I'm talking about development environment not production of course) and see exactly what the problem is. This will also help u in the future.